# Inconsistent font spacing between specific letters

Tags: html, css, web, fonts

I'm using a font called Nunito. Specifically weights 600 and 700. This font is imported on my website using Google Fonts with this line of code

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:600,700');
```

Now, if I write letters `ší` on my website the spacing is weird as you can see here

[image: my website]

The code on my website is nothing but simple HTML. It may be worth mentioning that I'm using VueJS.

```
<h3>Největší</h3>
```

However, writing the same word inside Google Fonts displays spacing correctly.

[image: same word but on Google Fonts]

Frankly I have no idea why that is.

**EDIT:** This seems to be happening only on my workstation.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:600,700');
```

```html
<h3>Největší</h3>
```

Comment: what browser are you seeing this? since it looks fine to me on chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/kaqct1xj/1/

Comment: Latest Chrome. I'm also getting same results on the latest Safari and the latest Firefox.

Comment: @Riskbreaker this is interesting. I opened your link and I see same wrong spacing.

Comment: yeah im in latest- I guess letter spacing or kerning could be a help- try looking at it now: https://jsfiddle.net/kaqct1xj/3/

Comment: This yields same results for me. It appears to be related to my workstation. I have no idea why.

Comment: yeah you try on another station mate and see what happens - could possibly be a mime type settings you have on your framework or etc

Comment: Do you have the Nunito font installed on your machine? If so, your machine will use the installed version rather than the Google Fonts version. Perhaps the local font file itself is the problem.

Comment: @Turnip this solved my problem, thank you

Comment: You could download the GF CSS and rename the font family to something like `_Nunito` so the system is forced to use that font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had installed the same font on my laptop and browsers were using installed version.

Comment: How come it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS may be it helps!!And if that CSS is not works for you try to use remove import url from CSS and add link in the html.
Step to include in html are :-

1) Remove import from CSS

2) Inside the head tag include below link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" /> 

body,h3{letter-spacing: normal;font-family:Nunito;}
```